# Alternative methods for auto-refreshing midori web-browser

Tags: midori

I was hoping to know if there are different ways of refreshing a website 'www.mywebsite.com'

Midori is the most favoured as you can do the following from the terminal:

```
midori -a http://www.mywebsite.com/ -i 120 -e Fullscreen
```

This will open midori to open www.mywebsite.com and refresh at every 120 seconds (= 2 minutes).

There is also the option of writing a bash script, in which the code 'simulates' as if the <kbd>F5</kbd> (aka refresh key) is being pressed :

```
#!/bin/bash

DISPLAY=:0 xdotool search --name ci-monitor windowactivate --sync key F5 >> ~/log/tmp.log 2>&1
```

and calling it from the crontab. The frequency can be altered/set via the crontab.

**Q:** Is there any other way of auto refreshing at set intervals?

Comment: Have you looked at [luakit](http://mason-larobina.github.io/luakit/)? You can fully script this browser - I use it for kids' programming classes to avoid them going to all sorts of unwanted webpages, but I'm sure you could script it to do autorefresh .. plus it runs a lot faster than midori.

Answer (score 3):

How about in the code of your website?

If you put the following in the HEAD section of your page, it will auto-refresh every three seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" >
```

There are other methods available to accomplish the same thing, ranging from JavaScript and other client-side applications to server-side code.

Can you be more specific as to what you are attempting to accomplish?  Also, I am not sure this question belongs in this area any more if we get into browser refreshing...