# Epiphany browser auto refresh

Tags: raspbian, web-browsers

I am trying to have a webpage open 24/7 using my raspberry pi2 running raspbian. I want the epiphany browser to auto refresh the page it is on every 200 seconds.

Is there any thing I can do to make this happen?

I am a full raspbian noob and need some help, please.

Comment: you could simulate pressing the F5 button CLI:
echo key F5 | xte

Comment: I have the same challenge.  Shame no-one has a solution.  It looks like we might have to upgrade to Raspian Jessie and use the Midori browser.  It has a command-line option to auto-refresh.  See second solution here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/auto-refresh-for-midori

Comment: This is also a simple, neat solution: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31683/alternative-methods-for-auto-refreshing-midori-web-browser